# Simple MVC Timer- Swift

Tags: swift, timer, swift3, nstimer, countdown

I know this is a super basic question, I am trying to refactor my code atm and am running into trouble with the timer. All I am trying to do is just get a simple countdown timer to print to the console

Here is my code snippet right now

VC------

```
var seconds = 60

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.modelInstance.gameTimerMethod(timeParam: self.seconds)     
}
```

MODEL-----

```
func gameTimerMethod(timeParam : Int)  {
    gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(decreaseGameTimer(secondsParam:)), userInfo: timeParam, repeats: true)
    print (timeParam)
}

func decreaseGameTimer(secondsParam: Int) {
    var printNumber = secondsParam
    printNumber -= 1
    print (printNumber)
}
```

Ideally what I want this to do in the console is simply countdown from 60 for now at a rate of one number per second. Although the console is logging at a rate of one number per second, it is for some reason repeatedly logging the number 105553117734207, instead of a 60 seconds countdown.

Thanks!

Comment: make the `printNumber` as a class variable of the Model. don't define it in method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed to `decreaseGameTimer` is the `Timer` instance.  It has a property `userInfo` that has a reference to the object passed to the `Timer` constructor.

Create a `class` to hold your count, and then pass an instance of that class to the timer's `userInfo`:

```
class Model {

    class TimerInfo {
        var count: Int

        // Pointer to function or closure to call when value changes
        var callback: ((Int) -> Void)?

        init(start: Int, callback: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
            count = start
            self.callback = callback
        }

        deinit {
            print("TimerInfo deinit")
        }
    }

    @objc func decreaseGameTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
        if let userInfo = timer.userInfo as? TimerInfo {
            userInfo.count -= 1

            // call callback with new value
            userInfo.callback?(userInfo.count)

            print(userInfo.count)
            if userInfo.count == 0 {
                print("done")
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    func gameTimerMethod(timeParam: Int, callback: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(decreaseGameTimer),
                                 userInfo: TimerInfo(start: timeParam, callback: callback),
                                 repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // The closure that follows the gameTimerMethod call is using trailing
    // closure syntax.  It gets passed to gameTimerMethod as the second
    // parameter named callback.  This closure will get called every
    // second until the timer finishes.

    self.modelInstance.gameTimerMethod(timeParam: self.seconds) { value in
        self.label.text = "\(value)"
    } 

    // Just for fun, lets run a second one at the same time
    self.modelInstance.gameTimerMethod(timeParam: 10) { value in
        self.label2.text = "\(value)"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please accept my answer by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left to turn it green.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, how would I go about passing the userInfo.count back into a UILabel in the VC? As I am having trouble now displaying the actual countdown on an actual label. Thanks Again!

Comment: See updated answer.  By storing the trailing closure in the TimerInfo object, we make it possible to have multiple timers running simultaneously updating multiple `UILabel`s.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `printNumber` as class variable instead of put in method, So it will not be reset everytime it called by the timer.

Also in `gameTimerMethod`, set the `printNumber` to `timeParam` before call the timer.

Your model will be similarly like below:

```
class YourModel {
    var printNumber = 0

    func gameTimerMethod(timeParam : Int)  {

        printNumber = timeParam
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(decreaseGameTimer(), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        print (timeParam)
    }

    func decreaseGameTimer() {
        printNumber -= 1
        print (printNumber)
    }
}
```